# oracle raw datatype in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of RAW type in my database. How can I use it in where clause?
i.e to get only values with third byte equal to 4.
this does not work:

```
SELECT v from T where v[3]=4
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the functions of the [UTL_RAW](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm) package to interact with raws, for example:

```
SQL> create table test (a raw(16));

Table created

SQL> insert into test values ('FF00FF00FF');

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from test where utl_raw.substr(a, 3, 1) = 'FF';

A
--------------------------------
FF00FF00FF
```

Comment: UTL_RAW link above gives a 404. The following link works, though today : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_raw.htm#BABFGDDG

Answer (score 3):

in **Oracle** :
you can use [HEXTORAW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions073.htm#SQLRF00649) function

- select * from TBLTest01 where (BINCOL=hextoraw('f0f0f3') )

it is in other databases in another way. for example in **DB2** :

- select * from TBLTest01 where BINCOL=BINARY(x'F0F0F3')

Answer (score 0):

One can also use REGEXP_LIKE function to select rows with RAW datatype:

```
select * from test where REGEXP_LIKE(a,'^....04.*')";
```

In my use case this method is a little faster than utl_raw.substr.